# Is directory traversal via request.url possible?

Tags: node.js

I'm coming from PHP, where you can inject double dots into a URL to try directory traversal. In NodeJS, it seems that you get the `Http` webserver automatically removes the double dots from the URL.

For example, if you go to `http://example.com/static/../app.js`, it seems like Node redirects to `http://example.com/app.js`, which then throws a 404 in my case, because there is no callback for URLs not starting with `/static/`.

**Is it safe to assume that directory traversal via `request.url` is *not* possible in a NodeJS HTTP webserver created using the `http` package?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was gonna say that you can be sure that it's not possible, then I tried and I have to say that no, it doesn't seem like the http module removes '/../'. The redirection you saw is done in the browser. So whether it's a security risk or not depends on how your static handler is implemented.

Proof of concept:

```
// Server
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(req.url);
}).listen(1337);
```

Curl it:

```
curl  --path-as-is "http://localhost:1337/static/../app.js"
# /static/../app.js
```

So if you use a homebuilt static handler that just uses path.resolve() you're screwed. Hopefully popular ones like express.static have thought about this, but i haven't tried it.

**Update**

Express indeed responds with a 404 "Error: Forbidden".

Comment: Note that curl will remove '/../'. Try with `curl --path-as-is "http://localhost:1337/static/../app.js"`